90s cartoon with scientists fighting alien creatures that evolve
I am looking for a '90s cartoon, probably american (I watched it in italian, so I am not sure about it). 
It is about a group of scientists that fight against some alien creatures. 
Those creatures evolve during the episode: at the beginning of the episode they look like pink worms, then they change: they become reptiles, then mammals or, when close to water (a lake or a river) they become fish; some of those creatures become sentient and work like over-lords that gives order to the others. 
The scientists use some liquid containing Selenium (I am sure about this) to stop and invert their transformation: this makes the creatures to become star-fish.

Sounds like Alienators: Evolution Continues (AKA Evolution: the Animated Series) from 2001-2002.

Taking up where the movie Evolution (2001) left off, this animated series features Dr. Ira Kane, Dr. Henry Block, Wayne Green, along with new character Lt. Lucy, as they try to stop the spreading of the alien organisms known as the Genus. Each episode features the Genus evolving into a new form of life, infecting the Earth. 

I'm almost certain that like in the movie, they use Selenium to fight the aliens. Here's the intro:




Ha I was gonna say it sounds like the movie Evolution. I didn't know that was made into a cartoon.

Also you are correct, I'm pretty sure its selenium. The main thing I remember is they determine that the best mass source of selenium is Head & Shoulders shampoo

Indeed, as is explained in Catija's excellent answer here.
